# Spring Rest Integration - Process different messages with the same endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to study how Spring Integration works (with extramly difficult, on the net there are a tons of source code but without some real step-by-step tutorial) and i would like to use it in my own application.

I will have to write a client/server application where the server endpoint is a Webservice and the client will be a Standalone app.

The standalone app will collect some data (creating different POJO, because each kind of that have different members) and next will invoke a WebService that store it in database.

The idea is to have a single REST Endpoint on WebService, in this way i dont have to create different one if i will have to expand my Standalone app.

My problem is: because the Endpoint will be only one, there is a way to apply some "transformation" when the webservice is invoked so i can manage different data?

For example:

```
Standalone app collect data (class1) -> Invoke webservice -> Webservice apply some transormation regardless Class1 type -> Save the data

Standalone app collect data (class2) -> Invoke webservice -> Webservice apply some transormation regardless Class2 type -> Save the data
```

So, each class have its own "transformation" that know what to do with this data.

A better real example could be this:

- Class1 - Is a class with a single member (a String)
- Class2 - Is a class with two member (a String and a Integer)

The Standalone App invoke wbs passing it Class1, the wbs with (transformation?) manage Class1 and store the data

The same process will be replaced to Class2

*Doing this flow, when later i will have to expand this applications, i will have to write only the transformation (on wbs side) and how the data have to be collected (on Client side).*

Someone could show me some starting point (tutorial, examples ecc) on this kind of argument ?

Unfortunally, with my low experience with SI i really dont know where to start with this argument. I just have seen that this framework have a lot of functionality and maybe exists something that handle this.... but i dont know how to find :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) and read the Spring Integration Reference and look at the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples).

In your case, you could use a [Payload Type Router](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-payloadtyperouter) to route the messages to different flows based on the inbound payload type.

Creating a step-by-step tutorial for every use case would be an enormous task.

We're happy to help further if/when you have specific questions; consider contributing a sample when you get it working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In those days i've read a lot, on the net and in documentation. I've studied the "Cafe" application (provided in SI examples) but without some step-by-step tutorial is a little difficult :) Sure, example and documentation are very well written... but if a people (like me) is about get starting, is really difficult to learn looking only some code or just reading an API style :)

Comment: Hi Gary, do you think i'm complicating life to want use SI to manage this Webservice aspect ? Because of my inexperience i could lose the real meaning of SI. Maybe i could provide a reply with a better workflow so you can help me a little more on how i can structure this app using SI? This framework is intresting and i would like to create this application using it on first to learn the framework and then to write a better code :)